# iptables requires POSTROUTING for port forwarding

Tags: iptables, firewall, router, linux-networking

I have a very basic router/firewall running Ubuntu. I want to forward tcp connections on a specific port (443) to one of the machines in the local network. It has one interface to the outside world (eth0) and one to the local network (eth1). Following one of the many guides available I set up iptables like this:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1:44]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:44]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3:187]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2:120]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination ip-localmachine:443
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I see if it works by setting up a simple server listening to port 443, on the local machine:

```
nc -l 443
```

But it doesn't receive any messages when connecting to it from the outside. Now, if I add one rule to POSTROUTING:

```
-A POSTROUTING -d ip-localmachine -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j MASQUERADE
```

Everything suddenly works as expected. Can someone explain what is going on here. Why do I need to add this last line, when all the guides I've found so far does not include this step.

Comment: It's because there is no rule available for natting outgoing packets in your list. Have you enabled packet forwarding? Can the local machine access internet?

Comment: I have enabled packet forwarding and yes, the local machine can access internet, even without the last line. What kind of rule are you referring to?

Comment: Can you try without the `-m tcp` option and see if it works?

Comment: The `-m` option is added automatically unfortunately

Comment: What do you mean by automatically? I thought you are manually entering the rule. Anyway, I don't see any reason to use -m and the way it is used is also wrong:  `match = -m matchname [per-match-options]` and it is not to define protocol.
.

Comment: I mean that when I don't write it out, it is still added with an `-m` in the iptables list.

Comment: It looks like your "local machine" doesn't have a default route through your router/firewall, so that it doesn't route return packets through that system. Using masquerading means it just has to return packets *to* that system, which works because it's on the local network.

Comment: @wurtel I've added the router as default gateway using `route add default gw router-ip`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Can you post your full firewall rules list (`iptables -S`), `sysctl -a`, and link to documentation you have followed? I'm sure then it will be possible to find out what is missing.

Comment: @bengal Here are the outputs: http://pastebin.com/nPGcxhCY. And the documentation: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s1-firewall-ipt-fwd.html

Comment: Could you please provide an output of `ip r` and `ip a` from router and lan machine wich is accessed by dnat rule?

Comment: Run `tcpdump -lnn -i eth0 port 443` on both hosts while you're testing, and add the output to your question.